# Connected socket information

Tags: windows, winsock

Hallo, how it is possible to get information form connected socket. I need to get address of server, the socket is connected to and port. Is this possible to get?

I need to figure it out in WSPSend, to block it or not. So i cant remember it form previous actions(like socket(),connect() etc..)

thx.

Answer (score 2):

[getpeername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738533.aspx)